# ListView + CheckBox =?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gmail-like ListView with checkboxes (and using the ActionBar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841283/gmail-like-listview-with-checkboxes-and-using-the-actionbar)

I need :

ListView with

```
items { CheckBox, then TextView } ;
```

when you press on the CheckBox , item should change it's color.

How can I get it ?

P.S.

In other words I need a ListView with CheckBoxes like in Gmail app

Comment: [Show us your efforts, what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: and when you say "list item should change color" does that mean the background, the text, the checkbox?

Comment: You can check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841283/gmail-like-listview-with-checkboxes-and-using-the-actionbar and get you answer.

Comment: toadzky , I mean ListView's item completely  change it's color

Comment: [Lmgtfy](http://bit.ly/WRrHIV) or [Lmgtfy](http://bit.ly/WRsU2K)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is quite simple! There's a component called `CheckedTextView` which is a combination of a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. 
This component might simplify your logic, leaving you free to do modify anything you want in your list's `OnItemClickListener`!

I've wrote an example for you:

```
    public class CheckBoxListView extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Mock data
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };

        //android's simple_list_item_multiple_choice is a CheckedTextView
        //try creating your own later ;)
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) arg1;

        //The change color logic is here!
        if(item.isChecked()) {
            item.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            item.setChecked(false);
        }
        else {
            item.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            item.setChecked(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your post is the only one which pointed me  on the right way!

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter and set listeners on checkboxes that will change what you want. (I'm not posting any code until I see what you've done on your own).
If you don't know how Android docs are really good place to start. For this issue you should especially check LayoutInflater, BaseAdapter, ListActivity and creating xml resources (layouts to be exact).

Comment: The MAIN thing I can't understand is how from CheckBox's click listener I can affect ListView's item .

Comment: here is the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645822/android-getting-the-relevant-listview-row-on-checkbox-changed