# Check item in ListView (ListActivity) on create

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I need to have something like settings ListView with checkboxes, but content must be dynamically added, not from XML (loading names of files from folder).

How It's possible to have ListActivity with checkbox which remember settings?
List like this
[ListView + CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821663/listview-checkbox)  [image: ListView from post above]
(long answer) look like good way to go, but I don't know how to **check something onCreate()**. I want to save strings in `SharedPreferences` and when app is closed and again reloaded it check what has been checked before.

Or, is there any better way to do this?

Thank You very much for answers.

Comment: i already did a sample using sharedprefrences if you want i will send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you required to do is just set preference for an item when u check it.
Then after when activity is recreated, set listview adapter and **setChecked(true)** for checkbox on listview_row according to preference

Comment: yes, it was like this - adapter was necessary. And here is pretty example of list with adapter - then I just added some things about preferences and it worked.